# WebAssembly (Avalonia) Uncaught ManagedError: One or more errors occurred. (Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime.)

Tags: c#, .net, webassembly, avaloniaui, avalonia

I've created my browser app with AvaloniaUI, and it has next code, called from App.axaml.cs:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => client.GetStringAsync(_apiBaseUrl));
    task.Wait();
    var content = task.Result;
    return Deserialize<TState?>(content) ?? new();
}
```

This code throws PlatformNotSupportedException, when I run **browser version** of application:

> Uncaught ManagedError: One or more errors occurred. (Cannot wait on
> monitors on this runtime.)

Same error occurs when I try to use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `Task.Run()`

Does somebody know how to make http requests from browser app?

It would be nice to have ability to reuse same code for browser and desktop version.

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to use sync version, because method `public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()` has void return type, and exception handling would be a trouble, as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET on Browser (and in general for the most part) doesn't support multithreading. .NET 8 will bring some multithreading support only on the newest browser versions, but it's still going to be limited.

And you can't block the main thread in either way.

> Does somebody know how to make http requests from browser app?

Use async methods without blocking.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = await client.GetStringAsync(_apiBaseUrl);
    return Deserialize<TState?>(content) ?? new();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know that `async void` is not a good idea, and it need to be tested, but for now `async void` is the best solution for calling method (`public override async void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()`)

Comment: `async void` could be a bad idea only if you don't handle errors. If you make sure there are no unhandled exceptions, it's fine.

Comment: @DavidLevin Please see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=net-7.0) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45552897/handling-exception-from-non-awaited-task) for more info how to get around potential exceptions.